# Why does my program for the Chudnovsky algorithm give the wrong result?

Tags: python, pi

I am trying to code the Chudnovsky algorithm in python. However, when I run my code, it gives me a very small number (-5.051212624421025e-55) which is not pi. I am in middle school, and I don't know anybody that can help me. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a link to the Chudnovsky formula: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/generating-the-value-of-pi-to-a-known-number-of-decimals-places-in-python-e93986bb474d

Here is my code:

```
import math

def fact(exi):
    memory = exi
    for i in range(1, exi):
        memory *= i
    return memory

k = 10
s = 0

for i in range(0, k):
    a = -1^k
    b = fact(6*k)
    c = (545140134*k) + 13591409
    d = fact(3*k)
    e = (fact(k))^3
    f = (3 * k) + 3/2
    g = math.pow(640320, f)

    numerator = (a*b*c)
    denominator = (d*e*f)

    s += (numerator / denominator)

s *= 12
print(1 / s)
```

Here is my updated code:

```
import math

def fact(exi):
    memory = exi
    for i in range(1, exi):
        memory *= i
    return memory

k = 17
s = 0

for i in range(1, k):
    a = (-1)**i
    b = fact(6*i)
    c = (545140134*i) + 13591409
    d = fact(3*i)
    e = (fact(i))**3
    f = (3 * i) + 3/2
    g = math.pow(640320, f)
    num = (a*b*c)
    den = (d*e*g)
    s += (num / den)
s *= 12
print(1 / s)
```

Comment: I think this site is more suitable for your question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Anyway, add some comments and give your variables meaningful names to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two mistakes:

1. When comparing with the formula shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm), it looks like you should use the iteration variable `i` (named *q* in the formula) where you currently use `k` in the loop. In your code `k` is the upper bound for `i`.
2. The exponentiation operator in Python is `**`, not `^` (which is bitwise XOR).

Comment: I found another small problem. If only change xor operator to exponentiation operator, there will be a priority problem. The exponentiation will be carried out before 1 takes negative.

Comment: @MechanicPig Yes indeed. Needs to be (-1)**k

Comment: I think I fixed the problems that you pointed out.  Can you check to see if I understood your feed back correctly?